# How to call a JAR files multiple times with the same instance?

Tags: java, command-line, jar, command, executable-jar

My program loads a few files once for each instance (when they are needed for the first time). The problem is when called through command line, every call creates a new instance. Now my program is called from another subsystem in a loop and since every time it has to load all those files, it is very slow.

So is there a way to somehow keep a reference to an instance of the program and execute commands on the same instance every time? Any other solutions to this?

Answer (score 1):

Either you have to implement the loop inside your program so it will be called only once.

Otherwise you need to start your program as a daemon and make it waiting for commands, either on stdin or a socket or pipe for commands.